# SQL time extending to next day

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables.

## MAP

```
 Product    Channel  Date   Advt Time 
Air    Pix  30-04-2011  22:23:16
Air    Pix  30-04-2011  23:55:08
```

## MBA

```
 Product    Channel Date    StartTime EndTime 
Air    Pix  30-04-2011  22:00:00   01:00:00
Air    Pix  30-04-2011  23:00:00   02:00:00
```

I have to check whether AdvtTime in MAP is between the StartTime & EndTime in MBA table.

I used the below query

```
select distinct * 
from MAP 
inner join MBA on (MAP.Channel     = MBA.Channel 
                   and MAP.Product = MBA.Product 
                   and MAP.ProgDate=MBA.ProgDate) 
where AdvtTime between ti and tii
order by Channel asc
```

But as the End Time extends till next day  it gives no results.
Pls help me on how to proceed further.

I want:

- `22:23:16` to match `22:00:00` to `01:00:00`, and
- `23:55:08` to match `23:00:00` to `02:00:00`.

Comment: What are the column types of the date and times?

Comment: Assuming that the time intervals in the MBA table spans less than 24 h, you know that EndTime < StartTime if the interval extends into the next day. Then you can use the test `AdvTime >= StartTime AND (EndTime >= AdvTime OR EndTime < StartTime)`

Comment: your end time don't make sense,  22:23:16 falls under both

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  Data type of Progdate is date and Advttime,StartTime and EndTime is time.

Comment: @ChendurSrinivasan Why wouldn't 23:55:08 match both? Also, please add an example of an entry after midnight that should match.

Comment: @TerjeD.  Thanks for that . It matches the values before 00:00.
i.e 22:23:16 matches 22:00:00 to 01:00:00.
But if there is 00:00:05 in the place of 22:23:16 it doesnt seem to show between 22:00:00 - 01:00:00

Comment: Then you have to add a test for MBA records for the previous day that has `StartTime >= EndTime and EndTime >= AdvTime`.  However, the best solution would be to use `datetime` for all of StartTime, EndTime and AdvTime as you then need only one `between`test in the where clause as in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should give you the answer you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM MAP
INNER JOIN MBA
ON MAP.Channel = MBA.Channel
AND MAP.Product = MBA.Product
WHERE (MAP.Date = MBA.Progdate
       AND AdvtTime >= StartTime
       AND (AdvtTime <= EndTime OR EndTime < StartTime))
      OR
      (MAP.Date = dateadd(DAY,1,MBA.ProgDate) -- extended from yesterday
       AND EndTime < StartTime                -- iff EndTime < StartTime
       AND AdvtTime <= EndTime)
ORDER BY MBA.Channel ASC
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e49f/1/0 to test it.

However, it would be better to combine the dates and times into datetime fields, and then extract the separate parts when needed for presentation purposes.

Comment: D

One small favour pls. If the Duration i.e( StartTime - EndTime) is less than one hour i need a buffer of + or - 5 mins. IF Start TIME IS 22:00:00 AN EndTinme is 23:00:00, 21:55/23:05 should match the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct * 
from MAP 
inner join MBA on (MAP.Channel     = MBA.Channel 
                   and MAP.Product = MBA.Product 
                   and MAP.ProgDate=MBA.ProgDate) 
where (AdvtTime between ti and tii) or (AdvTime between ti and DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(HH,AdvTime, tii),tii))
order by Channel asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this option with simple JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM dbo.map m JOIN dbo.mba m2 ON m.Product = m2.Product
                                 AND m.Channel = m2.Channel
                                 AND m.[Date] = m2.[Date]
                                 AND (m.[Advt Time] > m2.[StartTime] AND m2.[StartTime] > m2.[EndTime] 
                                   OR  m.[Advt Time] BETWEEN m2.[StartTime] AND m2.[EndTime])
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed23d/2)